# Python. How to edit data in text database?

Tags: python, database, file, text, url-rewriting

I have a little database text file db.txt:

```
(peter)
    name = peter
    surname = asd
    year = 23
(tom)
    name = tom
    surname = zaq
    year = 22
    hobby = sport
(paul)
    name = paul
    surname = zxc
    hobby = music
    job = teacher
```

How to get all data section from for example tom? I want to get in variable:

```
(tom)
    name = tom
    surname = zaq
    year = 22
    hobby = sport
```

Then i want to change data:

```
replace("year = 22", "year = 23")
```

and get:

```
(tom)
    name = tom
    surname = zaq
    year = 23
    hobby = sport
```

Now add(job) and delete(surname) data:

```
(tom)
    name = tom
    year = 23
    hobby = sport
    job = taxi driver
```

And finally rewrite that changed section to old db.txt file:

```
(peter)
    name = peter
    surname = asd
    year = 23
(tom)
    name = tom
    year = 23
    hobby = sport
    job = taxi driver
(paul)
    name = paul
    surname = zxc
    hobby = music
    job = teacher
```

Any solutions or hints how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I you are going to do many queries like "add job" or "change age", you should consider migrating your data to a SQLITE database, which is a much more adequate solution to store and manipulate data than a non-standard text file.

Comment: Is your question more like "which structure should I use" or like "do I really have to read and write the whole file everytime a single bit if information changes?"

Answer (score 2):

Using [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) as suggested by @aitchnyu and making a little modifications on the original format makes this an easy task:

```
import yaml

text = """
peter:
    name: peter
    surname: asd
    year: 23
tom:
    name: tom
    surname: zaq
    year: 22
    hobby: sport
paul:
    name: paul
    surname: zxc
    hobby: music
    job: teacher
"""

persons = yaml.load(text)
persons["tom"]["year"] = persons["tom"]["year"]*4   # Tom is older now
print yaml.dump(persons, default_flow_style=False)
```

Result:

```
paul:
  hobby: music
  job: teacher
  name: paul
  surname: zxc
peter:
  name: peter
  surname: asd
  year: 23
tom:
  hobby: sport
  name: tom
  surname: zaq
  year: 88
```

Of course, you should read "text" from your file (db.txt) and write it after finished

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to Sebastien's comment: use an *in-memory* SQLite DB. SQLite is already embedded in Python, so its just a few lines to set up.

---

Also, unless that format cannot be changed, consider *YAML* for the text. Python can readily translate to/from YAML and Python objects (an object composed of python dicts, lists, strings, real numbers etc) in a single step.

http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML

---

So my suggestion is a YAML -> Python object -> SQLite DB and back again.